# Why does Linq to Nhibernate produce an outer join

Tags: nhibernate, oracle9i, linq-to-nhibernate

I have an issue with Linq to Nhibernate producing queries with outer joins.

For example:

```
return Session.Linq<ClientContact>().Where(c => c.Client.Id = 13).ToList();
```

Produces a query similar to:

`SELECT...
FROM   mw_crafru.clientcontact this_, 
       mw_crafru.client client1_, 
       mw_crafru.relationshiptype relationsh4_ 
WHERE  this_.clientid = client1_.clientid(+) 
       AND this_.relationshiptypeid = relationsh4_.relationshiptypeid 
       AND client1_.clientid = :p0;:p0 = 13`

Notice the outer join this.*clientid = client1*.clientid(+). Boo!

To resolve the issue I went back to using Session.CreateCriteria.

```
return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (ClientContact)).Add(Restrictions.Eq("Client.Id", clientId)).List<ClientContact>();
```

Produces the following query:

`SELECT...
FROM   mw_crafru.clientcontact this_, 
       mw_crafru.client client1_, 
       mw_crafru.relationshiptype relationsh4_ 
WHERE  this_.clientid = client1_.clientid 
       AND this_.relationshiptypeid = relationsh4_.relationshiptypeid 
       AND client1_.clientid = :p0;:p0 = 13`

Notice no outer join this.*clientid = client1*.clientid. Yay!

Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server at least, a many-to-one mapping with `not-null="true"`, or `Not.Nullable()` using Fluent NH, causes Get operations to use an inner join instead of a left join. Try adding that to your mapping for Client in ClientContact.

Comment: I have tried that. We are hitting an Oracle database and using Fluent NH. My ClientContact mapping class has the following reference:

References(x => x.Client).Column("clientid").Not.Nullable().LazyLoad();

Comment: Then it's probably a bug or by design in LINQ to NHibernate.

Comment: I'm fairly certain Jamie is correct...the (current) linq provider only does left outer joins.

Comment: Take a look on query plan. On sql server 2008, I've got the same query plan for both "join" and "left join" query versions when there was a where clause testing a column of the right side table.